# Wordpress - add category to index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, categories

I have a category set up for "song of the week". On the desktop version of my site it appears in the sidebar as a widget.

However, I'm trying to display it on my mobile site. Previously my theme maker had me add the code to `index.php` to add a search bar to my mobile site.

So far, I've tried adding the category by using the "widget shortcode" add-on.

I've tried adding the following to my index.php:

```
<?php 
    echo do_shortcode(widget id="rpwe_widget-6");
?>
```

But when I do that, I get a 500 error.

What is the proper PHP code to add a category (1 post) to the `index.php`?

I know this short-code method isn't the correct way, but I'm unsure of what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get posts by using the loop and giving it a parameter to look for. In your case, you need to find out the ID of the category you want to show. To do so, go to your category overview and hover over the category you want to show.

You'll then see a link at the bottom of your browser, something like:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=category&tag_ID=1&post_type=post...

the part with category&tag_id=X
```

X is your ID of the category, which you want to show. Then in your front-page.php, home.php or index.php you can query the database with the following code (So yeah, put that in your template file):

```
<?php
    // Feed PHP with the information you want to show, in our case: a certain category = use of the id, number = amount of posts to show
    $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=1' );
    // Let WordPress run the loop for you
    while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<!--Inside the loop, you can use the WP template tags to show the stuff you want, like author, exerpt of the post etc. -->
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php // Don't forget to reset the query (clean the data after it is finished) ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

To help you with your problem: look for the category ID, enter the number in the rounded brackets **where it says cat=3** (3 is an example category). Then copy the code into your theme at the place you want, and see what you get :)

Hopefully your result.

This little query will give you:

The linked title of the post, and the excerpt (short preview of the post).
For more tags/information to show please visit the WordPress Codex or just do a goole search like so: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wordpress-loop-beginners-guide

Comment: Thank you for your help, user2521387! To get me by temporarily today, I've used the corrected shortcode method that Fencer04 posted. I will be testing this method later in the week, because that's one less plugin I need running!

Comment: This method works!! I have a follow up question, which I understand might need a new post. When I was using the shortcode/widget method, in my css I was able to do: `}
.rpwe-title > a {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "league_gothicregular" !important;
    font-size: 23px;
}
.rpwe-title {
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
}
.rpwe_widget-6 {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
}` in my css to format. How would i format this code in my css?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the brackets and some quotes in the code. Try using this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[widget id="rpwe_widget-6"]'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, Fencer04, this did fix get the shortcode method working! I will be using this temporarily until I get a chance to test user2521387's method with the loop.

Comment: Please accept this answer so I can get credit. This is the correct answer for the question you asked.

Comment: This method worked initially. However, when the item in that category is changed, the change shows on desktop, but mobile doesn't seem to change.

Comment: Do you have any caching setup on the pages? I'd be happy to take a look at it for you if you'd like.

Comment: I do not have caching setup, that's why I'm confused about why it wouldn't change. I figure it was probably a hiccup in the "widget shortcode" plugin or an issue with it being a "rpwe" with the widget being a "recent posts extended widget" instead of just being a normal widget category.(I hope I explained that right) I ended up using the PHP method below and it works fine. Now I just need to figure out how to get it on homepage only.